How to make a cone with an ellipsoidal side
Does anyone know how to make a cone (or cylinder) where one face is spherical and the other is elliptical? The aim is to kind of "enlarge" the spherical projection over 1 axis.
Thanks,
E


Why not just scale one face on X or Y?

In this cause I don't have a face on the edge, it is empty. Is it possible anyway?

yes just select the edge loop if there is no face then scale S on the X or Y or Z if it is lying down.

add a cylinder -> go to edit mode, select the bottom face -> press E

then S (scale) X

